# Testing for xs:choice in Delphi

Tags: xml, delphi, xsd

I am working with an XML document that includes xs:choice. Only one of the choices can exist in the document.
How can I test for the choice at run time?
This is a fragment of the document schema created with XMLSpy.

```
<xs:element name="Mount">
                                        <xs:complexType>
                                            <xs:choice>
                                                <xs:element name="AzEl">
                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                        <xs:attribute name="MaximumAzimuth" type="xs:float" use="required"/>
                                                        <xs:attribute name="MinimumAzimuth" type="xs:float" use="required"/>
                                                        <xs:attribute name="MaximumElevation" type="xs:float" use="required"/>
                                                        <xs:attribute name="MinimumElevation" type="xs:float" use="required"/>
                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                </xs:element>
                                                <xs:element name="DriftScan">
                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                        <xs:attribute name="Azimuth" type="xs:float" use="required"/>
                                                        <xs:attribute name="Elevation" type="xs:float" use="required"/>
                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                </xs:element>
                                                <xs:element name="BirdBath">
                                                    <xs:complexType>
                                                        <xs:attribute name="Test" type="xs:string"/>
                                                    </xs:complexType>
                                                </xs:element>
                                            </xs:choice>
                                            <xs:attribute name="Manufacture"/>
                                            <xs:attribute name="Model"/>
                                        </xs:complexType>
                                    </xs:element>
                                    <
```

I have tried:

```
if ChildNodes['AzEl'].NodeValue <> null then
```

and:

```
if Mount.AzEl <> nil then
```

But these don't discriminate between elements that are in the document and those that are not.
I am using Delphi Seattle, Windows 10, XMLDocument and the Binding wizard.

Comment: Can you post an excerpt of the XML that actually matches that schema? With the out of context portion you've provided, it looks like `<Mount>` should contain a single child element with a name that is one of *AzEl*, *DriftScan* or *BirdBath*. That means that the reference would be to `Mount.ChildNodes[0]`, AFAICT.

Comment: Ken - Your right on the context. Name is only one of AzEl, DriftScan or BirdBath (types of antennas BTW). The construct that I found that works is:
     if ChildNodes[0].LocalName = 'BirdBath' then

Answer (score 1):

The construct that does seem to work is:

```
     if ChildNodes[0].LocalName = 'BirdBath' then
```

Thanks to Ken White for that lead to the answer.